# Calculating the $n$th root of a number using logarithms

Tags: logarithms, wolfram-alpha

Supposedly, you can calculate the $n^{\text{th}}$ root of any number using logarithms. Where you find the log of the number under the radicand, divide that by $n$ and take the antilog of that.

I tried that with $\sqrt[5]{37}$, and something went wrong because I got an output of approximately $5$ even though Wolfram Alpha says it's about $2.0589\ldots$.

The code I entered into WolframAlpha was AntiLog(Log(37)/5).

> **Question:** What went wrong, and what is the *correct* way to do this?

***EDIT:*** If possible, could you also include a website or pdf or *something* where you can look up $\log(x)$ and $\text{antilog}(x)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, WolframAlpha uses base $e$ for AntiLog, but base $10$ for Log.

Comment: Typing "exp(ln(37)/5)" will give you what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question to include an extra request. Hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha says it's "Assuming "Log" is the natural logarithm." If you try $e^{\log(37)/5}$, you'll get [what you're expecting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(log(37)%2F5)%20%3D%3D%2037%5E(1%2F5)).

Comment: I edited the post and added another request. Could you try to answer that too?

Comment: [Here's an old book with log tables](https://books.google.com/books?id=piNNAAAAMAAJ&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5&dq=table+of+logarithms&source=bl&ots=N5ClLDW9RU&sig=_o-pc1HMwgPGgeMYZe7B7f6Ap4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizt4nn98fQAhVP_mMKHRI9DoE4ChDoAQgvMAM#v=onepage&q=table%20of%20logarithms&f=false)